# Color Picker For Ubuntu 19.10 (and later releases as well)

Tags: software-recommendation, colors

EDIT: I use X11 now and I have no problem.

I've seen many apps posted here, but right now in my laptop with 19.10 none of them work.

I've tried [Agave](https://www.linuxlinks.com/agave/), [Gpick](http://www.gpick.org/), and [Grabc](https://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/grabc/grabc.html) .

They all give back the color black regardless of where I put the cursor on `#000000`

Comment: is there a workaround?

Comment: Are you really using 9.10, or did you mean to type 19.10? Please click [edit] and fix it if that's what you meant.

Comment: That's expected behavior if you are using Wayland. In Wayland, applications do not have permission to see pixels outside their own box. (Yes, it's a reported bug). The workaround is to logout and login to an X session. Use the little 'gear' icon on your password screen to select Ubuntu using X.

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10 from 2009-October?  or Ubuntu 19.10 from 2019-October. There is a decade of difference between them...

Comment: Sorry all! Yeah I meant 19.10

Comment: @user535733 thank you!

Comment: @igorgue I posted a workaround, well actually is much more than a simple workaround. I hope you find it useful and if so would be so kind to accept it as a the correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO it is not very efficient to open Firefox to pick colors, at least I wouldn't do that, especially because you can implement Ubuntu native tricks like @Porcupine answer, which I'd like to expand, in two separate ways.

### CLI command

Indeed you could open BASH and type a command to get the color selection tool with `zenity` (works in Wayland and X11 and, on Ubuntu 22.04, requires no additional libraries):

```bash
zenity --color-selection
```

you can even automatically copy the output (which is an RGB color) with the following command, that can be conveniently set as an alias:

```bash
zenity --color-selection | xsel --clipboard
```

But if you, like me, find this a bit painful, read on.

### Keyboard shortcut + HEX output

If you want to take stuff to the next level, you can set the above command to be called via keyboard shortcut. To do that:

- re-write the above command as a function
- bonus: append some functionality to convert the RGB output to HEX (which is what I need for instance in React Native and could be useful to others as well)

  - e.g. convert `rgb(255,255,255)` to `#ffffff`
- encapsulate it into a `my_function_script.sh` file

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function pick-hex() {
  # Pick a color and return it into the clipboard as HEX, not RGB

  # Use Zenity to select an RGB color
  color=$(zenity --color-selection)

  # Remove the "rgb(" prefix and ")" suffix
  color=${color#rgb(}
  color=${color%)}

  # Split the color into individual RGB values
  IFS=',' read -r red green blue <<< "$color"

  # Trim leading spaces
  red=$(echo "$red" | xargs)
  green=$(echo "$green" | xargs)
  blue=$(echo "$blue" | xargs)

  # Convert RGB to hexadecimal
  red_hex=$(printf "%02X" "$red")
  green_hex=$(printf "%02X" "$green")
  blue_hex=$(printf "%02X" "$blue")

  # Combine the RGB values to form the hexadecimal color
  hex_color="#$red_hex$green_hex$blue_hex"

  # Copy the color to the clipboard for use in other applications
  echo -n "$hex_color" | xsel --clipboard
}

pick-hex
```

Once the above is in place, setup a keyboard shortcut for this script in Ubuntu:

- go to"Keyboard Shortcuts"
- add a new custom shortcut and click the "+" or "Add" button.
- in the command field, enter the path to your script (e.g. `/path/to/my_function_script.sh`).
- assign a custom key combination to the shortcut e.g. I like <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

and you end up with a legit color picking tool called via keyboard from anywhere in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround.

Open your image, a screenshot you made or a web page with Firefox.

file:///your_directory/your_image.png

In Firefox go to :
Tools > Web Developer > Eyedropper

Left click on the color you want.
It's copied in the clipboard.

For example : 
Hex: #497FC1

Answer (score 2):

Works in Wayland and X11

`zenity --color-selection`

Comment: While I can understand the confusion, this isn't what the OP wants. He wants to point at a color he sees on the screen and find out what color it is.

Comment: @MDeBusk And what does my answer does?

Comment: It's not so much what it does, but what it doesn't do. A color selection dialog lets you choose a color from the particular window displayed in the dialog box rather than anywhere on the screen.

Comment: @alfx Hi! Your [suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1324525) was rejected because it actually is a proper answer that deserves being posted separately! So can you please post it as such? Thanks! And do ping me here (as @beastofcaerbannog) If you do post it, so that I can upvote it!

Comment: hi @BeastOfCaerbannog, I did as you recommended, thanks for the advice

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Enjoy your points! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the X11 *native* solution that

- doesn't require any external packages like Agave, Gpick, or Grabc etc.
- and it doesn't limit to web pages (like the previous answer) either

Just run `xmag`. From its man page:

- The  `xmag` program allows you to magnify portions of an X screen.
- The area can be dragged out to the desired size by pressing Button  2.
- Once  a region has been selected, a window is popped up showing a blown up version of the region in which each pixel in the source  image  is  represented  by  a  small square of the same color.
- *"Pressing Button1 in the enlargement window shows the position and RGB value of the pixel  under the  pointer  until  the button is released"* -- this, is the X11 native solution for Color Picker.